# Closed-form solution of a system of nonlinear differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given is the system of nonlinear equations

$x'(t) = \frac{x(t)}{x(t) + ay(t)} - \gamma x(t)
\\ y'(t) = \frac{ay(t)}{x(t) + ay(t)} - \gamma y(t)$

with $a, \gamma \in \Bbb [0, \infty[$. I am wondering if there is an explicit solution for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$.

For $a = 1$ one can find a solution of the form

$x(t) = A e^{\mu_1 t} + B e^{\mu_2 t}
\\ y(t) = C e^{\mu_1 t} + D e^{\mu_2 t}$

However, when I tried this as an ansatz for the general case $a \in [0, \infty[$, it did not yield a solution as it led to a contradiction.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve the system of nonlinear equations for the general case $a \in [0, \infty[$?

Comment: You could look at $z = x+y$, which gives you the equation $z' = 1 - \gamma z$. This could be plugged into one equation or the other to obtain for example $x'=\dfrac{x}{(1-a)x+a z}- \gamma x$ and solve it for $x$.

Answer (score 1):

With **CAS** like **[Maple](https://www.maplesoft.com/products/Maple/students/)** I have 2 solution:

.

[image]
.

$$ \left\{ x \left( t \right) ={\gamma}^{-1}+{{\rm e}^{-\gamma\,t}}{\it 
C1},y \left( t \right) =0 \right\} 
$$
and second solution in implicit form:
$$ \left\{ -{\it C1}\,\sqrt [a]{y \left( t \right) {{\rm e}^{\gamma\,t}}
}-{\it C2}-{{\rm e}^{\gamma\,t}}+y \left( t \right) \gamma\,{{\rm e}^{
\gamma\,t}}=0,x \left( t \right) ={\frac {-\gamma\, \left( y \left( t
 \right)  \right) ^{2}a- \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}y \left( t
 \right)  \right) y \left( t \right) a+ay \left( t \right) }{\gamma\,y
 \left( t \right) +{\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}y \left( t \right) }}
 \right\} 
$$